# Execute a textual SQL query on an IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

I am trying to convert `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` using SQL query. I am not sure if it's possible.

```
        var id = "123";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ID = " + id;
        var dataSource = new List<Book> {
                new Book{ ID = "123", Title = "HarryPotter"}}.AsQueryable();

        var expected = dataSource.ConvertToIEnumerable(queryString); //IEnumerable type
```

The `dataSource` variable has type of `IQueryable`. Is there any way to pass the `queryString` variable in order to convert the `expected` variable has type of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: `.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: @john But how do I pass the `queryString` with the `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're doing. What is `ConvertToIEnumerable()`? How does it understand a string and apply it?

Comment: @john it's pseudo code. Just ignore this method... I am looking for a real method to convert

Comment: So your question, more accurately, would be "How do I execute a textual SQL query on an IQueryable?" - is that correct?

Comment: @john yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to query `List<T>` in memory using [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). I do not believe that there is a built-in way in .NET Framework.

What you *can* do is to use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) that provides SQL-like or lambda syntax to collections.

```
var id = "123";

var dataSource = new List<Book>
{
    new Book{ ID = "123", Title = "HarryPotter"}
};

var find = dataSource.Where(i => i.ID == id);
```